# Call a controller Action when using route group

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I want to call an action of a controller in laravel blade, when using router group...

route

```
  $router->group([
      'namespace' => 'Admin',
      'middleware' => 'auth',
    ], function () {
        resource('admin/adsense', 'AdsenseController');
        resource('admin/post', 'PostController');
    });
```

So, I want call an action of `adsenseController` in the blade template

```
{!! Form::model($var, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['what should i write to call an action ']]) !!}
```

Example (without router groupe)

route

```
Route::resource('subject','SubjectController');
```

blade template

```
{!! Form::model($var, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['subject.actionName']]) !!}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use action, try to use this:

```
'action' => 'SubjectController@index'
```

Instead of this:

```
'route' => ['someroute']
```

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#opening-a-form

Comment: Nice :) but the adsenseController is in a folder so should  I create it like this : 

'action' => 'Admin/AdsenseController@update'

Comment: Yes, you need to use namespace as in example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

> So , i want call an action of adsenseController in the blade template

Why don't you simply point your form's action directly to the controller? Eg

```
{!! Form::model($var, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => 'Controller@method']) !!}
```

If you want to redirect to a custom route, it's this simple

```
{!! Form::model($var, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => 'route.name']) !!}
```

Check out the [documentation on Laravel.com](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form)

Comment: Nice :) but the adsenseController is in a folder so should  I create it like this : 

'action' => 'Admin/AdsenseController@update'